# Issue loading JS function onload

Tags: javascript, function, onload

I am trying to set it so the borders change color on different elements on my site based on which page the user is currently on.  I am using PHP to determine the page, and then setting the variable `$color` (within the JS function) based on the PHP determination

For some reason, this will not work at all. I've even tried putting the function in a onmouseover to see if it would work, and it would not.

I must have an error somewhere within this JS function. I've got other ones that I've put together, and they are working fine. I am very new to JS, so I may not pick up on the obvious errors yet.

Here is the JS function I am trying to load.

```
function colorchange($color) {
    var $header = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
    $header.style.borderColor = $color;

    var $contentblock = document.getElementsByClassName('contentblock');
    $contentblock.style.borderColor = $color;

    var $rightfloat = document.getElementsByClassName('rightfloat');
    $rightfloat.style.borderColor = $color;

    var $footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer');
    $footer.style.borderColor = $color;

    var $mainimg = document.getElementsByClassName('mainimg');
    $mainimg.style.borderColor = $color;

    var $menucontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('menucontainer');
    $menucontainer.style.borderColor = $color;
}
```

I am calling it here:

```
<body onload="<?php echo $changecolor; ?>">
```

And this is the PHP snippet to determine the color.

```
if (isset($pageid)) {
    if ($pageid == "ministries") {
        $changecolor = "colorchange('#a52926');";
    }
    if ($pageid == "events") {
        $changecolor = "colorchange('#a54a4c');";
    }
    if ($pageid == "prayer") {
        $changecolor = "colorchange('#459979');";
    }
    if ($pageid == "about") {
        $changecolor = "colorchange('#a55029');";
    }
    if ($pageid == "contact") {
        $changecolor = "colorchange('#469e47');";
    }
} else {
    $changecolor = "colorchange('#26996d');";
}
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements, not just one.  Because of this, you cannot do `.style` on it.  You need to loop through the returned elements and set `.style` on each one.

```
var $header = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
for(var i = 0, len = $header.length; i < len; i++){
    $header[i].style.borderColor = $color;
}
```

**EDIT:** I suggest giving all the elements you want to change the color of the same class (for example: `changeColor`).  That way you don't need all those different `getElementsByClassName` statements.

```
function colorchange(color) {
    var colorChange = document.getElementsByClassName('colorChange');
        for(var i = 0, len = colorChange.length; i < len; i++){
            colorChange[i].style.borderColor = color;
        }
}
```

Comment: Would I be better off changing them from Class to Id in my css sheet and div tags, and also changing it to getElementsById in the js?

Thank you for the reply by the way!

Comment: @ZachHarner: You can use IDs if you want, just remember that IDs are **unique**.  You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.  Also it's `getElementById` (there's no `s`).

Comment: @ZachHarner: Actually, a *much better* idea is to give all the elements you want to change the color on the same class (say `colorChange`), then you can easily change all of them with one `for` loop.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again for the help! I'm going to give this a try :)

Update: I ended up changing them to the ID's, and it worked. Which also btw, I did have elements in there instead of element, so THANK YOU for that tip. I would have been pulling my hair out (whats left of it) for another few hours over that one!

I think I'll be good keeping those as unique ID's,  I don't plan on using the names again for other styles since they are my main containers.